# Rotating a line about a point

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, rotations, isometry

Let $σ_P$ be the rotation about the point $P = (a, b)$ through an $180◦$ angle.

**a**) Find the equations of this transformation.

For this, using the translation and rotation isometries: $T_{(a,b)} \circ σ_P \circ T_{-(a,b)} = T_{(a,b)}$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        cos \pi & -sin\pi \\
        sin\pi & cos\pi \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x-a \\
        y-b \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ = $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2a-x \\
        y \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$  $

Where $T$ represents a translation. I skipped a few steps to save space on here but I believe this is what is being asked. I'm not sure if my thought process is correct on this.

**b**) What is the image of the line with equation $y = 5x + 7$ under $σ_P$ when $P = (−3, 2)$?

Using what I got in part **a**, $y = 5x + 7$ is a line passing through points $(0,7),(-1.4,0)$. Applying the rotation $σ_P$ to the points, I output, $(-6,7),(-4.6,0)$ respectively. The line passing through those points would thus be $y=-5x-23$ which is the intended image of the original line. My question is, did I do this rotation correctly despite the fact that I only rotated two points and used their slope to find a line?

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: It looks to me like you didn’t get the correct answer for part **a**: $b$ should show up somewhere in the equations. Check what happens when $(a,b)=(0,0)$ in your answer—that’s clearly not a 180° rotation about the origin.

Comment: Also, in part **a**, it looks like you’ve got the right idea, but you’ve written it down incorrectly. $\sigma_P$ is the rotation about $P$, so you should have something like $\sigma_P=T_{(a,b)}\circ R\circ T_{-(a,b)}=\ldots$, where $R$ is a rotation about the origin.

Comment: When $(a,b) = (0,0)$, we have $(-x,y)$. If anything, it's a reflection about the $y$ axis. $b$ was in the equations while I was simplifying the matrices. When the translation $T_(a,b)$ was applied, I had $b +(y-b) = y$. Which sort of makes sense. A 180 degree rotation about a point is like a reflection  and it should only affect $x$.

Comment: Ok, I under stand the notation part and will definitely fix that in my final draft. The question is  where i went wrong in $a$.

Comment: If you rotate $(x,y)$ 180° about the origin, you should get $(-x,-y)$, not $(x,y)$. Most likely you got the sign wrong on one of the $b$’s.

Comment: You are definitely right. The bottom should be $(2b-y)$. I made a mistake simplifying the matrices. Good catch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29424/discussion-between-amd-and-nid).

Answer (score 0):

Rotations and translations are rigid motions that carry lines into lines, and two points uniquely determine a line, so your approach to part **b** is legitimate.

Here’s an alternative: Parametrize the equation of the line, apply the transformation, and then eliminate the parameter, i.e., compute $\sigma_P\left(\begin{smallmatrix}t\\5t+7\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and then eliminate $t$.